# Regular expression to match something followed by two different string

Tags: regex

I have these lines:

- Antonio Mario has inflicted
- Giovanni Luigi inflicted

I want to have a regex that matches the lines above and gives me as result `Antonio Mario` for the first line and `Giovanni Luigi` for the second one.

If I use `(.*)inflicted` as the pattern I get:

1. Antonio Mario has
2. Giovanni Luigi

Thanks.

Comment: `^(\w+).*[ ]inflicted`?

Comment: Use `^(\S+).*inflicted`. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7DMMv/1).

Comment: But if i have this situation Antonio Mario has inflicted
Giovanni Luigi inflicted. I will get only Antonio e Giovanni but i want Antonio Mario e Giovanni Luigi

Comment: ([\w ]+)has inflicted|([\w ]+) inflicted

Comment: is possible to have result for only one group instead of 2 different groups?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thank you for the information. However, the OP did not mention Java neither did he/ she provide an example. (That was the reason why I suggested to delete the tag).

Comment: @FranzHuber23 You're encouraged to use another tag with [regex]. When you do so, it's implied that the pattern should be compatible with the language/tool used as the "other tag".

Comment: @Gian Didn't you mention that you have these in two separate lines? If so, both Wiktor's pattern and mine should work for you. You just need to use the multiline flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name doesn't contain whitespaces then you have to look for the first whitespace instead of the word "inflicted". I would try something like

`^(.*?)\s.*?$`

You can simply test regular expressions online for example with https://regex101.com/

**EDIT**

Depending on your comment also whitespaces are possible in the name. So we cannot search for the first occurrence of a whitespace. Instead try to use

`^(.*?)(\shas)?\sinflicted$`

Note: a name ending with " has" might get cut off. With this lines only as input you are not able to detect if it's part of the name or not.